# ion toast blocks focus on any input in Ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, input, toast

Case: I have a very simple form, and when the user clicks submit while it's invalid, I display a toast with an error message.

problem:
this problem only occurred after I had migrated to Ionic 6, while the toast is displayed I cannot focus on any input till the toast disappears.

any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue occurs because the toast steals focus from the inputs and
it has something to do with `tapindex` set to -1

solution:

```
   this.toast.removeAttribute("tabindex");
    await this.toast.present();
```

there is an open issue at their github repo.